# Can't generate QueryDSL's QClass with querydsl-spatial

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm setting up a spring boot project with querydsl-spatial.

This is the list of dependencies and configuration:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>service</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>        

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2023.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>          
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This this the type I'm using within the entity:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "geography")
private org.geolatte.geom.Point location;
```

However when I build the project I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.querydsl.sql.Configuration is not registered
at com.querydsl.codegen.AbstractModule.get (AbstractModule.java:99)
at com.querydsl.sql.spatial.SpatialSupport.addSupport (SpatialSupport.java:58)
at com.querydsl.codegen.AbstractModule.loadExtensions (AbstractModule.java:83)
at com.querydsl.apt.DefaultConfiguration.<init> (DefaultConfiguration.java:283)
at com.querydsl.apt.DefaultConfiguration.<init> (DefaultConfiguration.java:114)
at com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAConfiguration.<init> (JPAConfiguration.java:83)
at com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor.createConfiguration (JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:42)
at com.querydsl.apt.AbstractQuerydslProcessor.process (AbstractQuerydslProcessor.java:82)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1021)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:937)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1265)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1380)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations (JavaCompiler.java:1272)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile (JavaCompiler.java:946)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0 (JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper (JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1583)
```

For the record I've tried to switch to use `querydsl-maven-plugin`, however it seems like it doesn't support jakarta.